# I have a report with fact and dim tables how can i analyse these tables? i have just started to learn business intelligence

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, report, business-intelligence

I use visual studio reporting services and sql server. There is a report on reporting services. I have to analyse this report on sql server with dim and fact table so how can I do this?

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to set up so that you have the rdl file in visual studio? If so you can try and click Preview with the rdl file open to see what error you get.

Comment: In what way do you have to "analyse" it? Do you have to run a report? write a report? Find an answer to a question? Find some insight in the data?

Answer (score 1):

Halime,

A lot of reports either have code embedded in the RDL file in order for it to run the SQL or they call a stored procedure from your database. You might want to look there and see if there is either a stored procedure from a database being called or if there is code in the RDL copied and pasted on its own. In order for the SSRS report to run, it needs to have either a SP being called or a query embedded. That will help to find.

Upon finding it, you can then look for the SP in the server the RDL uses to run on or copy and paste the SQL code into your SQL handler and edit as needed.

As far as structure of Fact vs. Dim-- you can think of Facts as the main body of some group of information and dimensions being specifics that might be used to further enhance or give more information about information contained within the FACT. Usually one is joined to another through "Keys" that have been built into both tables.

Hope this helped :)